# Adjust Javascript audio navigation function

Tags: javascript

I have a javascript effect on a website whereby when you roll over any of the navigation bar link an audio clip plays. It already works well, the only issue is I only want one audio clip to play at any one time, e.g currently if you roll over several nav links in one go, several audio clips go off at once, how do I adjust the code so only one audio clips plays at any one time, even if you did happen to roll over several? I have pasted in the current code, Thanks

```
<ul id="nav">
    <li><a href="index.html" onmouseover="playclip1();">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="shop.html" onmouseover="playclip2();">Shop</a></li>
    <li><a href="about.html" onmouseover="playclip3();">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="invest.html" onmouseover="playclip6();">Invest</a></li>
    <li><a href="contact.html" onmouseover="playclip4();">Contact</a></li>
    <li><a href="projects.html" onmouseover="playclip5();">Projects</a></li>
    <li><a href="links.html" onmouseover="playclip();">Links</a></li>
</ul>
</div>

<audio id="soundclip2">
    <source src="soundeffects/gunshot.mp3">
    <source src="soundeffects/gunshot.ogg">
</audio>
<audio id="soundclip1">
    <source src="soundeffects/dogs1.mp3">
    <source src="soundeffects/dogs1.ogg">
</audio>

function playclip() {
  if (navigator.appName == "Microsoft Internet Explorer" &&
    (navigator.appVersion.indexOf("MSIE 7") != -1) ||
    (navigator.appVersion.indexOf("MSIE 8") != -1)) {
    if (document.all) {
      document.all.sound.src = "dogs1.mp3";
    }
  }

  else {
    {
      var audio = document.getElementById("soundclip1"); audio.play();
      audio.play();
    }
  }
}


function playclip1() {
  if (navigator.appName == "Microsoft Internet Explorer" &&
    (navigator.appVersion.indexOf("MSIE 7") != -1) ||
    (navigator.appVersion.indexOf("MSIE 8") != -1)) {
    if (document.all) {
      document.all.sound.src = "gunshot.mp3";
    }
  }

  else {
    {
      var audio = document.getElementById("soundclip2"); audio.play();
      audio.play();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: could it be possible to include and show the code in jsfiddle

Comment: Hi, all the code required to make this function work I have pasted in here (except the audio clip itself) - I will however look into jsfiddle.

Comment: Define a common class for all the <audio> Tags and before playing any audio Pause all the other audio by calling document.getElementsByClassName("AudioClass").pause();

Comment: Thanks Philemon, would it be possible to show an example of this? as I am a novice Javascript user, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know about the internet explorer compatibility, but this will work in other browsers.

Here is the code. It could be cleaner, but it works - and it's stricly in vanilla JS:

```js
var playing = false,
  audio,
  audioTags = "",
  listItems = "",
  animals = ['Bison', 'Birds', 'Bird1', 'Vehicle', 'Bird2', 'Ducks', 'Chirping'],
  urls = ['index', 'shop', 'about', 'invest', 'contact', 'projects', 'links'],
  currentlyHovered;

function playclip(file) {
  currentlyHovered = file;

  if (playing) return;

  audio = document.getElementById("soundclip" + file);
  audio.play();
  playing = true;
}

function resetTime(file) {
  audio = document.getElementById("soundclip" + file);
  audio.currentTime = 0;
  playing = false;

  if (currentlyHovered) {
    playclip(currentlyHovered);
  }
}

function unsetHover() {
  currentlyHovered = null;
}

for (i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
  listItems +=
    "<li><a href='" + urls[i] + ".html' onmouseover='playclip(28" + i + ");' onmouseout='unsetHover();'>" + animals[i] + "</a></li>";

  audioTags +=
    "<audio id='soundclip28" + i +
    "' onended='resetTime(28" + i + ");'><source src='http://www.noiseaddicts.com/samples_1w72b820/28" + i + ".mp3' /></audio>";
}

document.getElementById("nav").innerHTML = listItems;
document.getElementById("content").innerHTML = audioTags;
```

```css
ul {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  font-size: 1em;
  list-style: none;
  padding-left: 0;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover {
  color: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<ul id="nav"></ul>
<div id="content"></div>
```

Here is a **[CodePen Demo](https://codepen.io/dankreiger5/pen/yoKwzo?)** - I hope it helps.

Comment: Dan, that looks excellent - the only slight issue is even when you 'onmouseout' of the nav clip, I want the clip to keep playing till it finishes.

Comment: I've updated my answer. The code works on non-IE browsers. I'd have to dig a little deeper to come up with an IE safe solution.

Comment: Dan Kreiger - wow thanks excellent programming there and thanks for your help :) I have upvoted your answer but I don't have enough rep yet for it to show...

Comment: Thank you! You can also [accept the answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) no matter what your rep level is. However, maybe you should wait a few days before doing so in case someone comes up with an even better (and perhaps IE safe) solution. Actually, I'll update this answer again and strip out all the IE parts, since they aren't doing anything anyways right now.